# Django Model Table temporary data vs. permanent data

Tags: django, static, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I am writing a trip planner, and I have users. For the purposes of this question, lets assume my models are as simple as having a "Trip" model and having a "UserProfile" model.

There is a functionality of the site that allows to search for routes (via external APIs), and then dynamically assembles those into "trips", which we then display. A new search deletes all the old "trips" and figures out new ones.

My problem is this: I want to save some of these trips to the user profile. If the user selects a trip, I want it to be permanently associated with that profile. Currently I have a ManyToMany field for Trips in my UserProfile, but when the trips are "cleaned/flushed", all trips are deleted, and that association is useless. I need a user to be able to go back a month later and see that trip.

I'm looking for an easy way to duplicate that trip data, or make it static once I add it to a profile . .. I don't quite know where to start. Currently, the way it is configured is there is a trips_profile datatable that has a foreign key to the "trips" table . . . which would be fine if we weren't deleting/flushing the trips table all the time.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you have a field tripType in your Trip model and if this is set to "permanent" which means at least one user has it as a permanent trip, then don't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say exactly without your models, but given the following layout:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    trips = models.ManyToManyField(Trip)
```

You can clear out useless `Trip`s by doing:

```
Trip.objects.filter(userprofile__isnull=True).delete()
```

Which will only delete `Trip`s not assigned to a `UserProfile`.

However, given the following layout:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

You could kill the useless trips with:

```
Trip.objects.filter(users__isnull=True).delete()
```

The second method has the side benefit of not requiring any changes to `UserProfile` or even a `UserProfile` at all, since you can then just get a `User`s trips with:

```
some_user.trip_set.all()
```